# Flutter doctor --android-licenses error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java, flutter, java-home, flutter-doctor

I set **JAVA_HOME** and install **android SDK command-line Tools** but I still get an error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
```

This is my **`java -version`**:

```
java version "1.8.0_351"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_351-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.351-b10, mixed mode)
```

This is my **`javac -version`**:

```
javac 1.8.0_351
```

I also add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin` in **`path`** on Environment

Comment: Before this, I installed **Java version 17** and this problem did not exist in this version, but I had problems building the project with that version of Java.

Answer (score 2):

1、Uncheck Android SDK command-line Tools (latest)
2、Check Android SDK command-line Tools 8.0
3、Click Apply
In Windows, go to “C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools” and rename the 8.0 folder to “latest”
4、Run Flutter doctor again.

Comment: This worked for me in Mac too.

Android Studio > Settings > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Android SDK Command Line Tools  > Uncheck Latest > Check 8.0 > Apply Button